# Table of Python operand types

Tags: python, operator-overloading

In Python, as in many languages, `+` doesn't just add numbers, but also concatenate strings. More unusually, `*` applied to a string and a number, will concatenate N copies of the string.

I'm curious about what other things the standard operators in this language can do if given unusual operand types.

Is there a table anywhere of the operand types accepted by Python operators?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb Thanks! That does list all the operators, though it doesn't mention the surprising overload of `*` on sequences. I don't suppose there is a table anywhere that lists all the surprising overloads of operators on standard library types?